# LiveData retrieved from Room Dao doesn't notify its observers when Dao is updated from a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I suppose it's because two separate instances of Dao are used. I tried to make the room database into a kind of singleton and the dao lazy but the Broadcast receiver still uses a separate instance.

```
@Database(entities = [Timer::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TimerDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun timerDao(): TimerDao
    val lazyTimerDao by lazy {
        Log.d(TimerDatabase.toString(), "instantiate dao")
        timerDao()
    }

    companion object {
        private var db: TimerDatabase? = null

        fun getDb(context: Context): TimerDatabase {
            return db ?: instantiateDb(context)
        }

        private fun instantiateDb(context: Context) = synchronized(this) {
            Log.d(TimerDatabase.toString(), "instantiate")

            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                TimerDatabase::class.java,
                DB_NAME
            ).build()
        }
    }
}
```

The broadcast receiver reacts to an action from notification. The broadcast receiver deletes an item via using Dao. I want the changes to be visible in my app if it happens to be open when that happens, to display the new list of items, for example. I could do it by using Observer pattern and removing the item manually but is there a better way?

Comment: Are you using Dagger/Hilt in your project? If you make your database a singleton then any Daos related to it will be singletons too